# What GameEngine to choose

Tags: unity, blender-game-engine

I concider myself an amateur, but I have quite some experince in Unity3D.

Over the course of the next three years - before I can quit my job and go to colledge - I want to make ONE game.

Now the question that bothers me is which gameengine to choose:

A) Unity3D, because I know it well and the community is great (even though I didn't touch it for a year or so)

B) GoDotEngine, because it's open source, still beeing improved and very lightweight

C) Blender, because Python (though..who really uses blender for games? and I kinda hate blender)

Initially I wanted to go with GoDot, since it is  a lot like Unity and OpenSource, but I fear that the community is to small to help me out, if I get stuck and I really need to finish this, if I want to spend three years on it.

Comment: Hi, questions about "how to get started," "what to learn next," or "which technology to use" are discussion-oriented questions which involve answers that are either based on opinion, or which are all equally valid. Those kinds of questions are outside the scope of this site. Visit our help center for more information.
Go for unity ( my opinion )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its best to choose Unity 3D game engine. As its easy and quickly to learn. Excellent community help, even in my 1.5 year career I didn't stuck on a single task, Every time I got the solution. So, I always prefer Unity 3D.

Answer (score 0):

It depends mostly to the kind of game you are going to produce.

If you are going to prduce a FPS I can suggest  Torque 3D by Garagegames

https://github.com/GarageGames/Torque3D   <-  MIT license and HUGE community and tons of manuals and resources

An RTS is better done via Spring Engine HUGE community too

But tel lme what kind of game you are going to do and I'll edit this answer accordingly

Comment: This is kinda the problem - the genre itself should not be the limit.
But if you want me to be specific: I am going to make a 3d and 2d role playing game with the main focus on the world it takes place in.
So I need a powerfull engine (not in terms of graphics) to simulate it that let's me seperate core from visuals/ gameplay or better.. let's me implement a command line game that I wrote as it's core.

Comment: Unity is a good engine , but you have no access to source, to integrate your core engine you need the source code, my suggestions are full open sourced , perhaps Torque is the right choice for you.  Have a look